# Why did Church believe Barney owed him?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-expendables-2, the-expendables

In The Expendables 2 the team are sent in by Church because of the mess they made in Valena (he'd originally tried to hire the team to kill the General who ran the island).

However after Barney and Lee's scouting trip to the island they agreed to turn the job down. Why (assuming they didn't take money off Church) did they owe him anything for their subsequent mischief?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you're asking. They turned the job down but then still got entangled in all the chaos that happened in Ex 1 and caused major trouble. So why should Church *not* be angry at them? The question is, did the story of Ex 1 turn out in the way *Church* wanted, which I'm currently not sure of.

Comment: @SonnyBurnett I guess I'm just confused why they owe him if they didn't take the job. Even if they did Church wanted the general dead. Which happened - for free! He must have known their would be collateral, this is Stallone after all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well Barney owed Church because Church wanted the control of the island back. The island produces cocain and is used by the CIA (maybe to gain money from it and finance black operations).

In "The Expendables 1" Barney kills Munroe who previously killed the general. Munroe was a EX-CIA Agent. Besides the fact that Barney kills Munroe (who may have cooperated with the CIA), he plunges the military regime too. This fact makes it impossible for Church to get the control back over the island. If the military regime would be still there, he could possibly promote a new general and take him under his control.